# When you can recognize someone's character by taking a look on their faces

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, expressions

Dictionaries say: **to be a good/bad etc. judge of something** means:

> to be someone whose opinions about something are usually right, wrong, intelligent etc.

**Example:** 
- My sister is a very shrewd judge of character.

We have a term in our language which says i.e.

> - I am a good judge of **faces**.

**Connotation:**

- I usually can recognize the inmost feelings, intents, and the character of anybody who I take a look at their faces.

It implies that the person has experienced ups and downs of life and ran into various types of people so has been qualified to detect a normal person from an evil one.

Does this sentence make the same sense in natural English or I have to say something else to convey this message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "I am a good judge of character" is a more common expression in English, and it implies that you can tell a lot about someone just by looking at them or meeting them for a short period of time.

Comment: So @Mixolydian how about "judge of faces"? Does it sound awkward, odd or unnatural?

Comment: @A-friend "judge of faces" doesn't sound natural to me in English. It's not an idiomatic expression like "judge of character".

Comment: So how can I say that? Would it sound natural to say: "I'm a good judge of characters **by looking at prople's faces**" or just "I'm a good judge of characters **based on people's sight**" or something like that?

Comment: @A-friend neither of those sound good. "character" is always singular in this expression. Also, I don't think you need to say "by looking at people's faces" - it is understood. You could also say something like "I can take one look at someone and immediately know their whole life story." "To take one look at" is an idiom that is related to what you're trying to say: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/taking+one+look+at

Comment: So I can say: "I can take one look at anyone and know their character". Right?

Comment: @A-friend I suppose you could say that, sure.